# Datastructures for junior python programmer

Tags: python, data-structures

What datastructures should a junior python developer study first?

UPDATE:
I mean common datastructures, not python list, dict and tuple...

Comment: The ones described in any of the some 100(0?) books about data-structures and you would have found by basic research on your own. Knuth comes into mind. Before that, you should learn a major part of programming is to research on your own and not expect to be spoon-fed.

Answer (score 3):

The best reference for learning python is the python standard library itself. As for data structures, if you want to go deeper than the standard python type, you can study the [collections module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html). Have a look at the docs and see how it is implemented.

For instance with [IPython](http://ipython.org/), you can access the documentation of any object or module by appending "?" and the code by appending "??" (without the quotes).

To go beyond the standard library you can explore [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) which is the Python package Index, a repository of community contributed Python modules.
Pick packages with high weights and not marked alpha if possible.

For instance, on data structures you have :

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/data-structures/0.1.2

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/structures/0.5

I think that looking at real code is the best to learn real programming.

Comment: Is there any sense to read this books:
http://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-Introduction-Computer-Science/dp/1590282418/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1344325069&sr=8-3&keywords=python

http://www.amazon.com/Python-Algorithms-Mastering-Language-Experts/dp/1430232374/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344325121&sr=8-1&keywords=python+algorithms

Comment: Don't know those books. Of course I did not mean, you should not read books !